# pg_search dmetaphone not working after installing contrib package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, pg-search

After installing pq_search and running contrib package migration:

```
class InstallSomeContribPackages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute 'CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;'
    execute 'CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;'
  end

  def down
    execute 'DROP EXTENSION pg_trgm;'
    execute 'DROP EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;'
  end
end
```

It still throws error when migrating the dmetaphone migration:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function dmetaphone(text) does not exist
LINE 2:   SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT dmetaphone(unnest(rege...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted this question for anyone else that struggled with this...

Even with the contrib package I still needed to install the fuzzystrmatch extension.

Try rake db:setup and rake db:test:prepare

If that doesn't work then do the following for each environment:

Locally access you psql in terminal and create extension:

```
\psql
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
```

On heroku access your psql db and create extension from terminal:

```
heroku pg:psql
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
```

Then rerun migration. Hope this helps save someone else stress.

Comment: This was really helpful